# Security issue with IP address

Tags: ip-address

BBCi Player only works in the UK, but I am in another country so I cannot access.

How do they know that my IP address is in another country?

Comment: https://github.com/epidemics-scepticism/tor-misconception/blob/master/README.md#geoip-is-bullshit

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to Tor.

Answer (score 1):

It's called a geomapping, you can use Maxmind GeoIP or *lots* of similar services to guess a country by IP address. Use `StrictNodes 1` and `ExitNodes {gb}` in your `torrc` config to force using of UK exits

Comment: iPlayer blocks Tor

Comment: @canonizingironize then he's about to find the exits that are not blocked... Some **badass** services are blocking Tor, but nobody can block all the exits, so he's about to try&find

Comment: They also block VPS providers and a whole bunch of other ranges :)

Comment: @canonizingironize OMG.... For what reason?! But - after that - it's a side-effect of too few exit nodes, IMHO. If there were 100k+ exits - it would be near-impossible to block them all, even knowing their addresses